# 120/240 circuit extension

Tags: extension-cord, 120-240v

I have a 3-wire 120/240 V circuit running to my garage to an l14-30 outlet for an arc welder. Occasionally I want to run that arc welder in my basement. My thought is to cut the existing circuit in the basement and install a similar l14-30 outlet. And then put a junction box  on the remaining wire that goes to the garage with a flexible wire l14-30 plug.

Basically the wire to the garage then looks like an extension cord. Normally that "extension cord" is plugged into the new outlet and the garage is constantly energized. When I want to use the welder in the basement I unplug the "extension cord" and plug in the welder.

There may be other ways to do this, but I have some other uses for that "extension cord" and I don't want to complicate this note with those details.

Is this configuration allowed by code?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Why aren't you simply adding the second outlet and leaving the rest as-is? It's typically not allowed to hard-wire an extension cord or to have one installed for permanent use.

Comment: I have a power inverter in the basement. When there is a  power outage I can plug this extension cord into my inverter and  provide power to my garage . Not for the welder but for small power tools, lights, etc. I could also use that extension cord to connect my generator to my six circuit transfer switch, although the connector genders are wrong  necessitating some suicide plug wiring (no lectures, please).

Comment: I'm not inclined to spend my time advising how to comply with Code when you have established that Code is not important to you.  Backfeeding is more dangerous than you realize to not just you.

Comment: I am a highly qualified electronics technician with lots of formal engineering training..I assure you that I know exactly what I am doing. My weakness is my knowledge of the electrical code, not with the function and application of electricity. And although I used the term backfeeding I am not doing that into my main electrical panel, rather into the "front feed" of my six circuit transfer switch, sorry if that is confusing. If I didn't care about code I wouldn't be asking code questions.

Comment: @Frank2644 -- you know that those connector gender problems are fixable right? (i.e. you can get inlets to go in your wall if you need to take power from a cord and put it into the permanent wiring system :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I use such an inlet now for my generator. Now I'm sorry I mentioned my backfeed thoughts because it probably is distracting everyone from answering my initial question.

Comment: After thinking about ThreePhaseEel's comment: I guess if I used a male inlet box instead of a flexible extension dongle with a male plug it is more likely to comply with code.